# On the Chowla and twin prime conjectures

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm reading https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/chowlas-conjecture/ and at some point it is mentioned that, the twin prime conjecture is a variant of Chowla's conjecture that $\sum_{n\leq x} \lambda(n)\lambda(n+2) =o(x)$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Liouville function. Does anyone have a reference/proof of this result ? Also, what would be de Polignac's conjecture in terms of $\lambda$ ?

Comment: This is not known to be true. Tao claims this is a "variant" of the twin prime conjecture on the blog post you reference. It's possible that if one had a sufficiently strong quantitative version of the claim one could deduce the twin prime conjecture, but this certainly isn't known from a $o(x)$ bound.

Comment: @MarkLewko, okay, thanks. So, do you have any reference/proof that ''a sufficiently strong quantitative verson of the claim entails the twin prime conj'' ? Also, how strong should be the quantitative version ?

Comment: The variant is replacing $\lambda(n)$ with $\Lambda(n)$, where $\Lambda(n)$ denotes the von Mangoldt function, and extracting a main term.

Comment: You can find some details here https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/the-bourgain-sarnak-ziegler-orthogonality-criterion/